# Renaming table name in GCP dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am new in GCP.I am building a dataflow job moving data from Datastream to Bigquery using the [google provided templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#datastream-to-bigquery).
I am getting the following error `(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Table reference is not in [project_id]:[dataset_id].[table_id] format)`

which I believe is caused by a table that has space in the it's table name.

How can I rename the table name during this data transfer stage ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Beam validates table names using [this](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/73b1ef4c5252b910ece60fcfbb800f63ca99dc32/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L494) regex which doesn't support spaces. So this is probably a bug.
Could you file a Jira [here](https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/).

You can probably get around this by using a query instead of a table reference when reading using BigQueryIO.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a provided template, in the documentation you can review the configuration parameters. Seems like the foramt of the outputStagingTableNameTemplate parameter that you are trying to use is not properly configured. Can you check that the format is correct?

```
gcloud beta dataflow flex-template run JOB_NAME \
    --project=PROJECT_ID \
    --region=REGION_NAME \
    --enable-streaming-engine \
    --template-file-gcs-location=gs://dataflow-templates/VERSION/flex/Cloud_Datastream_to_BigQuery \
    --parameters \
inputFilePattern=GCS_FILE_PATH,\
gcsPubSubSubscription=GCS_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME,\
outputStagingDatasetTemplate=BIGQUERY_DATASET,\
outputDatasetTemplate=BIGQUERY_DATASET,\
outputStagingTableNameTemplate=[project_id]:[dataset_id].[table_id],\
outputTableNameTemplate=BIGQUERY_TABLE_log
```

For example, if the target table were a table from a [public google datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data) (which is not possible, it is just an example) the outputStagingTableNameTemplate parameter should be like this:

```
outputStagingTableNameTemplate=bigquery-public-data:covid19_italy.data_by_province
```

Where:

- bigquery-public-data is the project_id
- covid19_italy is the dataset_id
- data_by_province is the table_id

Comment: Thank you Juan for the reply. I tried to review the configurations as said, see my configurations  for the output staging
`outputStagingDatasetTemplate=dwingestion:mystem_lv_staging."Legal Status",`
If I run the job with the configuration it runs(though it's not loading data) but how will I run the whole job because, from the above, I will only run the job for the specific table ?,**Legal Status** the table I mentioned that has space in its table name.I have a whole schema with different tables that I would like to  move the data to Bigquery as part of the dataflow job

Comment: First, you need to remove the quotation marks on "Legal Status". On the other hand, It's not a good practice to have spaces in the table names. You should make a new table, change the table name to legal_status and migrate the data from the old one. The parameter should look like this: outputStagingDatasetTemplate=dwingestion:mystem_lv_staging.legal_status

Comment: Regarding the whole schema, you should investigate about it, there are several possibilities. For example, you could create a job per each table.

Comment: Hi @oyugi.collins, did it works?

Comment: Hi, @Juan Bravo this didn't work we had to rename the table from database level and restructure the code to start writing data to the new table without space in it's table name. As you had suggested writing jobs for each table, for us it would have been cumbersome since we have more than 50 tables that we need to load to Bigquery. Thanks for the help :) though!!